# How to make safe power supply?

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, voltage-measurement, electrical

I have a product which required 24 volt supply. I had experienced many times my product has been given more than 24 volt supply and system gone bad. Is there any way to privant the damage caused by high supply?
Ex: Is there any way to know voltage is more now I need to shotdown the system kind of thing?

Comment: It sounds like you need to measure the voltage, and turn of when there is something wrong, and you recieve too much voltage.

Depending on how much more than 24 volts you are expecting in fault conditions, the requirements will change.
AC/DC also matters, as well as the type of powersupply - Fully regulated switching supply, or just a transformer with (or without) a rectifier bridge?

Comment: Yes i want to know if it exceeds 24 volt but it can't be done manually all the time.

Comment: You still didn't respond to any of my actual questions. We can't really help you unless you give us more information

Comment: I want to know how can i prevant damage from power supply. By any kind of circuitry or any other ideas

Comment: I m using SMPS of 24 volt. Once my product was connected to spike buster with SMPS . There was a short in spike buster whole 220  volt has been supplied to my product . It got damaged i want to prevant this kind of situations

Comment: My board can only take 5 volt max.I m using internal dc dc converter to bring 24 volt to 5 volt so even if it exceeds more than 25 -30 volt or so my board will get more voltage and it will get damage

Comment: If these 24v supplies have gone bad frequently, it probably means you're doing something wrong. Perhaps you keep short circuiting something. So the answer might be to double check what you're doing before you apply the 24v supply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I gather from the additional explanation, one of the things you might be interested is a MOV (metal-oxide varistor) in combination with a fuse. The circuit would look something like this:

[image]

The MOV will start conducting as the applied voltage gets too high (you need to look for yourself which part will fit your requirements). When this happens, the Fuse will trip, disconnecting your product from the power supply, and protecting it from the overvoltage condition.